# How to verify one from many conditions is satisfied on Mockito? Is it possible to verify if one OR another method was called?

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito

On my unit test I want to check if one or another method was called. I can easily verify how many times some methods are called thanks to Mockito, but `verify` has no verification mode like "OR". Any workarounds?

In my case I want to check if on `SharedPreferences.Editor` was called `.apply()` or `.commit()` because two of this possibilities satisfies me and saves data. Unfortunately if I call `verify(mEditor).apply()` but someone will change implementation to `.commit()` in example due to requirement of instant save, the test will fail, but shouldn't because I want to only test from this point of view if data are saved or not. It's the unit test and should be independent from changes like that and checks only scope of what are tested inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around you ask for would be to catch the underlying [MockitoAssertionError](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/exceptions/base/MockitoAssertionError.java) (or just `AssertionError`):

```
try {
  verify(mEditor).apply();
} catch (MockitoAssertionError mae) {
  // apply was not called. Let's verify commit instead.
  verify(mEditor).commit();
}
```

Alternatively, if both `apply` and `commit` call some (internal) `save` method you could also try verifying that (assuming it is exposed -- mock-based testing can be at odds with information hiding). Or, if you have control over the code you're testing you could refactor it along these lines.

The better advice, though, would be to avoid the need for this altogether, as argued in the [answer by @GhostCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55560941/165292).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a good way of doing that, and honestly, I think the real answer is: do **not** do that. Yes, the other answer shows a way to achieve what you ask for, but then:

You know what your production code should be doing. Meaning: instead of writing a *single* piece of verification code that allows "this **or** that", rather write two independent tests, one for "this", and one for "that".

In other words: you control what goes into your tests. So write one test that should result in `apply()`, and one that should result in `commit()`. And then `verify()` that *one* case that each test is expected to see!

Unit tests should be straight forward. When something fails, you quickly look at the unit test and you already know where to look in the production code to spot the root cause. Anything that adds complexity to your tests might make that harder. It is better to have two tests that follow a clear "when then verify" path, instead of having one (or multiple) tests that go "when then verify this OR verify that".

Comment: Ok, you have good suggestions, but if I'll write two separate tests - one that should result in `apply()` and one in `commit()`, one of them will always fail, right? Or you mean only to focus on that I should know how it is implemented on production code? The problem is that both of this methods do what I (and my unit test) expects, both saves data. One do it in asynchronous way and second one do it immediately and both ways are acceptable here. Maybe I'm wrong, but when I'm looking and thinking from the test perspective I'm wondering what is minimum to meet the requirements from test name.

Comment: @user3054470 Sure, that is a blurry line here. But as said: individual tests should test one specific path. And that path should be clearly visible to a reader of that test. You see, at least when talking about a unit test, it makes a big difference if you expect that apply() is called, or that commit() is called. So why not have to tests, and each one goes for a specific goal? It might be different for a functional/integration test.